# Convert Text file into Array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, txt

So I've done a bit of researching and use a variety of different methods, but nothing seems to work. I'm trying to have a program read a txt file in my folder, then convert into an array so that a different program can call that program and initiate the program of the other.

Below is the current code I have.

The print is to test and see if the output is true. In return, however, I get []. It supposed to fill in things like Zero, Guskgu, Tyran, etc.

Note that I'm new to Python and currently using the most recent version 3.

```
profiles = []
def readFile(Users):
        fileObj = open("Usernames.txt", "r") #opens the file in read mode
        profiles = fileObj.read().splitlines() #puts the file into an array
        fileObj.close()
        return profiles
print(profiles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You constructed readFile(Users) but if you want to change profiles you need to call the method and pass in its parameters.

Im not sure what Users is but something like,

```
arr = readFiles(Users)
print(arr)
```

I removed Users and ran it with no parameters and it worked fine, also make sure the .txt file is in the same directory as your .py file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def read_file(filename):
    lines = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line.strip())
    return lines

print(read_file('filename.txt'))
```

The txt file:

```
lorem
ipsum
dolor
sit
amet
```

Output `['lorem', 'ipsum', 'dolor', 'sit', 'amet']`